# how can you overwrite or remove the signature "electron.app.Electron" from the desktop notification

Tags: javascript, node.js, notifications, electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to remove or overwrite my notification signature made by electron.

here is what i get:
[image]

I am trying to whether overwrite the signature electron.app.Electron or remove it completely, by knowing
that I have tested it on test mode (`npm run start`), and also when packed as `.exe`
also I have noticed that I remove the icon the signature goes a way, but it is very unpleasant without one.

my current notification code is bellow:

```js
function showNotification() {
  const notification = new Notification("new message", {
    body: "app launched",
    icon: __dirname + '/icon.ico',
    tag: 'soManyNotification',
    hasReply: true
  })
}
console.log(Notification.permission)
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  showNotification()
  //alert('we have permission');
} else if (Notification.permission === "denied") {
  Notification.requestPermission()
};
```

any help would be gratefully appreciated ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// If this is running on Windows then set UserModelID for notification

if (isWin()) {
    app.setAppUserModelId("Proper name to be replaced");
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, ^^ 
uhm, just for my documentation, how would it work for linux and other platefrom

Comment: No need to set for other OS