# Electron app notification states the app sending notification is electron.app.<App Name> even after packaging

Tags: electron, cross-platform, desktop-application

After making a basic CPU Monitor app (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f5yGQc4LFGj2baEjyHl5TT_LD5kM09uZ?usp=sharing) which sends notification when the cpu utilization goes over a certain percentage, I packaged the project. But the notification states that the app creating the notification is `electron.app.CPU Monitor` in place of `CPU Monitor`. How to exclude the unnecessary `electron.app` part?

[image: notification screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to have been answered recently: [how can you overwrite or remove the signature “electron.app.Electron” from the desktop notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64088839/how-can-you-overwrite-or-remove-the-signature-electron-app-electron-from-the-d)

On Windows, it seems that [app.setAppUserModelId()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetappusermodelidid-windows) must be called beforehand:

```
if (process.platform === 'win32')
{
    app.setAppUserModelId(app.name)
}
```

Comment: Even though it turned out to be a duplicate question, thanks a lot :)

Comment: this is very helpfull, as maybe also u know which method to set icon in front of this app title?