# How to change app name correctly in electron?

Tags: notifications, electron, label, customization

I am using the electron and developing the desktop application.
I have changed application's name and try change notification label.
[image]

```
app.setName("My Application");
```

By this code, app's title is changed "My Application".

```
const notification = {
    title: CustomNotyTypes[rows[i].notytype] + ": " + rows[i].notytitle,
    body: nBody,
    timeoutType: "default",
    timeout: 5000,
    appName: "Restoration Calendar",
    icon: nativeImage.createFromPath(
        path.join(__dirname, "resources", "icon.png")
    ),
};
new Notification(notification).show();
```

But "electron.app" label of system notification is not changed.
I want to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at same question on Stackoverflow.

[Notification from electron shows electron.app.Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859634/notification-from-electron-shows-electron-app-electron)

Anyway, I solved same issue using app.setAppUserModelId() method.

```
app.setAppUserModelId(app.name);
```